# How to grep a matching pattern in all the lines in a file except the first two lines

Tags: bash, shell

I have text file named contacts.txt with few rows populated. In this file first two rows are headers so I don't want to do anything in these two rows.

I want to get input from the user, search the contacts file, and display the matching rows. If go with `tail` piped to `grep` I get the exact data, but no headers. How can I get the header rows, too?

```
echo -n "Enter the value to search: ";read search1; echo -e "\n"
if [ $(tail -n +3  /root/scripts/contacts.txt | grep -i  $search1 | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "No matching rows found!!!! \n"
        echo -n "To re-enter press r. To go back to main menu press any key: "; 
        read reenter;
        echo -e "\n";
        if [ "$reenter" == "R" ] || [ "$reenter" == "r" ]; then
           remove_entry  # calling a function
        else
           inputscan # calling a function
        fi
else
        echo -n "Number of Matching rows found:"; tail -n +3  /root/scripts/contacts.txt | grep -i $search1 | wc -l; echo -e "\n";
        tail -n +3 /root/scripts/contacts.txt | grep -i "$search1" | column -t -s";";
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said your first two lines are header so modify your script like below to print the header as well:-

```
echo -n "Number of Matching rows found:"; tail -n +3  /root/scripts/contacts.txt | grep -i $search1 | wc -l; echo -e "\n";

#Print first two lines of the file
head -2 /root/scripts/contacts.txt 

tail -n +3 /root/scripts/contacts.txt | grep -i "$search1" | column -t -s";";
```

Comment: This separately prints the header rows. So when the greped rows are printed using column - output is not aligned

Comment: Enter the value to search: she


Number of Matching rows found:2


EmpNo  LName     FName       Division                Sub-Division
-----  -----     -----       --------                ------------
234   Test    User   Developer   Shell
900   skill   Test   coding      shell

Please enter the unique field from the above displayed rows to remove from the address book
Note: Your input is case sensitive :

Comment: `Enter the value to search: she


Number of Matching rows found:2


EmpNo  LName     FName       Division                Sub-Division
-----  -----     -----       --------                ------------
234   Test    User   Developer   Shell
900   skill   Test   coding      shell

Please enter the unique field from the above displayed rows to remove from the address book
Note: Your input is case sensitive :`

Comment: @Nike, modify your question with original data type and your excepted data type i.e what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, I made a few modifications to your script:

- put the contacts.txt file path in a variable, to avoid having to type it over and over again (and it's good it if changes later!)
- put the code that counts the number of matches in a variable, to avoid running that code twice
- added a `head -2` to output your header lines.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  echo -n "Enter the value to search: ";read search1; echo -e "\n"

  contactsfile='/root/scripts/contacts.txt'
  number_matching_rows=$(tail -n +3 $contactsfile | grep -i  $search1 | wc -l)

  if [ $number_matching_rows -eq 0 ]; then
          echo -e "No matching rows found!!!! \n"
          echo -n "To re-enter press r. To go back to main menu press any key: "; 
          read reenter;
          echo -e "\n";
          if [ "$reenter" == "R" ] || [ "$reenter" == "r" ]; then
             remove_entry  # calling a function
          else
             inputscan # calling a function
          fi
  else
          echo "Number of Matching rows found: $number_matching_rows"
          head -2 $contactsfile
          tail -n +3 $contactsfile | grep -i "$search1" | column -t -s";";
  fi
  ```

Comment: in this we are printing twice so the header row tabs may not be aligned with data.

Comment: a suggestion i got from one of my friend is too create a temporary file and redirect the header and also the greped lines. then print it using columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `head -2` and pipe the output of multiple commands by combining them in a curly brace block.

```
{ head -2 /root/scripts/contacts.txt;
  tail -n +3 /root/scripts/contacts.txt | grep -i "$search1"; } | column -t -s";";
```